# push javascript == undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou tentando mandar um objeto para dentro de um arrey para assim obter uma sequencia de objetos porém quando eu uso a função push ela da erro falando que ta undefined vou deixar os códigos abaixo:

```
objectArrey: Object[]
//esse é a minha variável onde todos os objetos tem que estar
```

```
//nesse código é onde eu faço um forEach no meu arrey que chegou da api a adiciono extraio desse objeto as informações necessárias e na hora do push da o erro Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.
this.api.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        let arreyAst = data.near_earth_objects['2015-09-08'];
        let ast = {}
        arreyAst.forEach(element => {
          ast = {
              name: element.name,
            }

          this.objectArrey.push(ast)
        });
        console.log(this.objectArrey)
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Deu erro ' + error)
      })
```

Código completo do ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiServiceService } from '../api-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-object',
  templateUrl: './object.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./object.component.scss']
})
export class ObjectComponent implements OnInit {


  objectArrey: Object[]



  constructor(private api: ApiServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getObj()
  }



  getObj(){
    this.api.getAll().subscribe(
      data => {
        let arreyAst = data.near_earth_objects['2015-09-08'];
        let ast = []
        arreyAst.forEach(element => {
          ast = [
            {
            name: element.name,
            }
          ]
          this.objectArrey.push(ast)
        });
        console.log(this.objectArrey)


      },
      error => {
        console.log('Deu erro ' + error)
      })
  }

}
```

Comment: Onde defines `this.objectArrey`? O que dá `typeof this.objectArrey, Array.isArray(this.objectArrey));` na primeira linha dessa função (antes do `forEach`)

Comment: eu não entendi muito bem, porém fiz isso e continuou dando erro.

Comment: Mostrou alguma coisa na consola?

Comment: a aplicação nem compila.

Comment: Cara consegui resolver, era um erro muito bobo que acaba passando despercebido, obrigado pela ajuda a solução é  objectArrey: Object[] = [] é so declarar um arrey vazio

Comment: ok, então tinhas um erro no TypeScript... esse erro deve ser visivel no compilador

Comment: não é não pow huahuau se não eu tinha lido o erro pow

Answer (score -2):

Para resolver é só trocar a variável objectArrey para a seguinte forma:

```
objectArrey: Object[] = []
```